# Convert XAML vector graphics to font

Tags: xaml, fonts, converters, glyph

Okay, I'll admit, this is a wild stab in the dark...I know virtually nothing about XAML or font creation, but here goes...

I have some XAML path data which represents individual characters, graphics etc, which I would like to export as a font. The aim is to create a font, similar to Segoe UI Symbol which can be distributed with web sites and applications, providing glyphs that can be dynamically coloured and scaled.

Are there any tools available which will allow this? I've looked into font creation software, but have not found anything yet that supports XAML data.

Comment: I don't know any tools that do exactly this job (even though i might be interested in that too).
But what you could do is converting the path to a vector graphic and then using tools to convert that into a font. (XAML Path -> Vector graphic format -> font). There are tools for both cases, a search engine of your choice will provide you with them.